# What's the name for the equivalence induced by a function on its domain?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, relations, equivalence-relations

Any function $f$ with domain $X$ induces an equivalence relation on $X$, with classes $$\{f^{-1}(\{y\})\,:\, y \in \operatorname{im}f\;\} .$$

Is there a name for this equivalence?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, the graph of the equivalence relation is the [kernel pair](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/kernel+pair) of $f$. I guess you could call it the ‘pullback of the equality relation from the codomain’ if you want...

Comment: I do not know about the name, it also seems that the notation varies quite a lot, e.g $X/f$ in Example 2.2.2 [here](http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/abstract_algebra/study_guide/22.html), i think I've seen $\theta_f$ too. Perhaps it is good to know, that every equivalence relation can be obtained in this way. This fact can be found in many standard textbook, to mention at least one - the first one google told me about - I'll give a link to Schechter's Classical and nonclassical logics [p.100](http://books.google.sk/books?id=70W4Q-kzdicC&pg=PA100).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $f:X\to Y$ then $f^{-1}(y)$ is called *a fiber*. The equivalence relation you defined is the partition of fibers of the function $f$.

I have not seen an explicit name for this, however it is common to say that $x_1$ and $x_1$ are in the same fiber, or explicitly in the fiber of $y$.

Answer (score 3):

"Having the same value under $f$ ". For instance if $f$ computes the absolute value, the equivalence is having the same absolute value. In some cases there is a special name, like "congruence modulo $n$" instead of "having the same remainder after division by $n$", but I don't think there is any dedicated terminology for the general case.

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, any function  $f$ induces an equivalence relation $E_f$ on its domain and this relation, according to [Algebra, 3rd Ed](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821816462) by Birkhoff & Mac Lane, is called the **equivalence kernel** of $f$. This term, together with the notation $E_f$ supplied above, is defined on page 33.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very easy-to-remember notation/terminology.