# $x\sim y\iff x^2\equiv y^2\pmod{\!6}$ is an equivalence relation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, relations

> Question 1: Let $x,y \in S$ such that $x\sim y$ if $x^2 =y^2\pmod6 $. Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

This is what I tried:
Reflexive: $x^2\pmod6 = x^2$  implying $x\sim x$
Symmetry: suppose $x\sim y$, then  $x^2 =y^2\pmod6$
Operating by inverse of $x^2$ both sides we have $e=(x^2)^{-1} y^2\pmod6$
Then I have $y^2=x^2\pmod6$, hence $y\sim x$
I would like to get some corrections up to here because am not sure with this

> Question 2. Find the orbits of the given permutation:
>    $$v:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\quad\text{ defined by }\quad v(n)=n+3$$

Here is my solution which I would also want somebody to correct me!
Let the relation $\sim$ be defined on $\mathbb{Z}$ by $a\sim b$ if $b=a+3$
I consider that the orbits of $v$ are the classes of $\mathbb{Z}$ with respect to $\sim$ given by 
$\{b\mid b=a+3\}$. Thus I get only three orbits which are $\{1,4,7,10,…,3n-2\mid n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, $\{2,5,8,…,3n-1\mid n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, and $\{3,6,9,…,3n \mid n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: What is $S$? Does x2 mean $x^2$?

Comment: Please ask separate questions.

Comment: And please try to use latex!

Comment: Despite the fact that you correctly write $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, your explanation makes it sound as if the only numbers you are considering are the *positive* integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument for symmetry of the first relation is flawed, because you do not know that there is such a thing as the inverse of $x$ modulo $6$ (for example, what if $x^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{6}$? ) But you don't have to: if $x^2\equiv y^2\pmod{6}$, then $6|x^2-y^2$, hence $6|y^2-x^2$, so $y^2\equiv x^2\pmod{6}$.

And you are still missing transitivity: if $x^2\equiv y^2\pmod{6}$ and $y^2\equiv z^2\pmod{6}$, why must $x^2\equiv z^2\pmod{6}$? (**Hint.** Just use the definitions).

Comment: ;thanks sir, do yo mean a divides b by b|a instead of b/a?

Comment: what about question 2, am i correct?

Comment: "$a|b$" means "$a$ divides $b$" means "there exists an integer $k$ such that $ak=b$". This is **different** from $b/a$ which denotes the rational (possibly integer) number you get by actually dividing $b$ by $a$. $a|b$ is a relation between $a$ and $b$; $b/a$ is a number resulting from performing an operation on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Question 2 is badly written, because the sets you describe *look* as if they were finite and start at the least positive integers. It is also false to claim that $\sim$ as you define it is an equivalence relation: it's not reflexive, it's not symmetric, and it's not transitive. So while it is true that there are three orbits, your argument is very confused.

Comment: :okay..i want to know more, is it possible for the permutation of a given set to have orbits, given that the relation involving a and b is not an equivalent relation?

Comment: @neema: Yes, they can; the problem is that the definition **you** gave is not an equivalence relation, not that there aren't any orbits. What you need to do is *fix* the definition of the relation, not question the underlying theory. Better definition: $a\sim b$ if and only if there is an integer $k$ such that $a=b+3k$. *Much* better definition: $a\sim b$ if and only if $a\equiv b\pmod{3}$. Now try to figure out *why* those equivalence relations are such that the orbits equal the equivalence classes.

Comment: thank u alot, i understand now!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $ $ Show more generally that if $\rm\ f\,:\,S\to T\,$ and $\rm\, \equiv\,\, $ is an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) on $\rm\,T,\,$ [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2389834/242) $\rm\ \{\:\! (x,y)\,:\, f(x)\equiv f(y)\:\!\}\ $ is an equivalence relation on $\rm\,S.\,$ It's called the (equivalence) [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(set_theory)) of $\rm\,f,\,$ if we view the codomain as the quotient set  $\rm\, T/\!\equiv\,,\, $ which above  is $\rm\ \mathbb Z/6,\,$ with $\rm\ f(x) = x^2\,.$

See also the more general notions of [difference kernels and equalizers,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equalizer_(mathematics)) and see this [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/89594/242) where the *fiber* viewpoint is mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for #1. Any relation defined via equality of the values of a function is an equivalence relation. More precisely:

If $f:X\to Y$ and $\sim$ is defined on $X$ by $x\sim y$ iff $f(x)= f(y)$, then $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

Conversely, every equivalence relation arises in this way.

Comment: Note that to apply this directly requires viewing $\:\mathbb Z/6\:$ as a quotient set, because it uses an equality $\rm\:f(x) = f(y)\:$ vs. a congruence $\rm\:f(x)\equiv f(y)\:.\:$ But even if the OP has not yet learned about quotient sets,  they may still comprehend this viewpoint by using congruence instead of equality - see my answer.

Comment: @Bill, yes, nicely put, thanks.