# Name for a set of pairs of elements that equalise two functions?

Tags: functions, terminology

Is there an established name for this $eql$ function?

$$\operatorname{eql}(f, g) = \{\ (x, y)\mid f(x) = g(y)\ \}$$

Comment: In category theory, such a set is exactly the equalizer object of the arrows $f$ and $g$ in the category of sets.

Comment: See [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/92322/242)

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equalizer_(mathematics)) it's called an equalizer even outside of category theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered through Reddit (see Bill's link) that this is called the pullback:

$$pb(f, g) = \{\ (x, y) \mid f(x) = g(y)\ \}$$

The equalizer is:

$$eql(f, g) = \{\ x \mid f(x) = g(x)\ \}$$

But we can define each in terms of the other:

$$pb(f, g) = eql(f \circ \pi_1, g \circ \pi_2)$$

$$eql(f, g) = pb(f, g) \cap pb(id, id)$$

Answer (score 0):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equalizer_%28mathematics%29) this set is called an *equalizer* of the two functions.