# Distinct elements of relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations, equivalence-relations

R is the relation on Z (integers) given by xRy ( X is related to Y ) 
if 3 divides (x-y),
what are the distinct elements of  R?

Comment: Can you come up with examples of elements of $R$? Non-examples? Is $1R5$? How about $3R9$?

Comment: No, theres no given example.

Comment: it has 4 distinct elements.

Comment: Which four elements is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two questions about equivalence relations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92271/two-questions-about-equivalence-relations)

Answer (score 1):

I would start by writing out what it means for 3 to divide a number, that is, $3 | n$ if and only if  $\exists k$ s.t. $n = 3k$. When does $3 | (x - y)$ is the next question we should ask ourselves. As suggested in one of the comments on your post, often this is where it helps to come up with some examples, for instance, does $1R5$? does $5R8$ ? does $8R5$ ? Now that we've considered some examples, lets expand on the definition a little, when $3 | (x - y)$ we have that $\exists k$ s.t. $(x - y) = 3k$ or alternatively, x is related to y whenever their difference is a multiple of 3.

Comment: thank you @BemjaminGadoua, can you give me one example of that.?

Comment: Can you tell me two numbers who have a difference that is divisible by 3?

Comment: 6 and 3 itself.

Comment: did you check $5R8$ as suggested?

Comment: the given is xRy therefore if 5R8 their difference is -3. is this still correct?

Comment: Does 3 divide -3? If yes then 5R8 is an element of the relation. Check 10R4, clearly there are more than two elements. A plain description is the last statement of my answer.

Comment: Thank You so much @BenjaminGaduoa its a big help for me.