# Equivalence Relations: $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ if and only if $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I need someone to check my proof.

Question: On the set $\mathbb{R}^2$ of ordered pairs define the 2-plane relation $\sim$ as follows 
$(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ if and only if $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$. Prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on R2

My Answer: 
We must show reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity.

**Symmetry**: $(a,b)\sim(b,a) \Rightarrow a^2+b^2=b^2+a^2$

**Transitivity**: Suppose $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ and $(c,d)\sim(e,f)$ 
Then $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ and $c^2+d^2=e^2+f^2$ 
Therefore $a^2+b^2=e^2+f^2$

**Reflexivity**: I am not sure - might need a little help with this.

Comment: For syymetry, you have to show $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ implies $(c,d)\sim(a,b)$ for all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$.

Comment: So what about this for symmetry:

Comment: (a,b)~(c,d) than f(a,b)=g(c,d). Thus, f(g(c,d))=f(c,d)=c^2+d^2 and g(f(a,b))=g(a,b)=a^2+b^2. Therefore f(c,d)=g(a,b). f(a,b)=g(c,d) implies f(c,d)=g(a,b) which equals c^2+d^2=a^2+b^2. Thus, (a,b)~(c,d) ==> (c,d)~(a,b). Or is that wrong?

Comment: I don't understand where the g and f is coming from. But it is not hard: $(a,b)\sim(c,d)\iff a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2\iff c^2+d^2=a^2+b^2\iff (c,d)\sim(a,b).$

Comment: Oh well thanks! I thought there was more to it than that but I guess I just over complicated something so trivial. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

It is also useful to note that if $A$ is a set, and we have a relation $\equiv$ such that $a\equiv b$ iff $f(a)=f(b)$ (Where $f$ is a function whose domain is $A\times A$), then $\equiv$ is an equivalence relation. In this case $f$ is the function that sends $(a,b)$ to $a^2+b^2$

Comment: This is called the (equivalence) [kernel](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/92322/23500) of $f,$ and the classes are called [fibers](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/89594/242) or *level-sets* (here circles).

Comment: @MathGems I didint know these terms before

Answer (score 2):

For reflexivity, it is enough to write that for all $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $a^2+b^2=a^2+b^2$...

Answer (score 1):

In this cant we say that (a,b)~(c,d) if they are on the same circle about the center because the radius square is equal. So this must be a equivalence relation with the classes being the circles about the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Your **transitivity** reasoning is correct, but for **symmetry**, as was commented, you rather need $(a,b)\sim (c,d) \implies (c,d)\sim (a,b)$.

For **reflexivity**, you need $(a,b)\sim (a,b)$, which is even more trivial than the others.