# $ (a,b), (c,d) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}\ $ let us define a relation by $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ if and only if $\ a + 2d = c+2b$

Tags: proof-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

Question:

For $ (a,b), (c,d) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}\ $ let us define a relation by  $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ if and only if $\ a + 2d = c+2b$

Is this an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$?

My attempt:

**Reflexive?**

Notice that $ \forall (a,b) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, a + 2b = a + 2b \implies ((a,b),(a,b)) \in R$.

Hence the relation is reflexive.

**Symmetric?**

If $ \ ((a,b), (c,d)) \in R \implies a + 2d = c + 2b \implies c + 2b = a + 2d \implies ((c,d), (a,b)) \in R $.

Hence the relation is symmetric.

**Transitive?**

If $ \ ((a,b), (c,d)) \in R$ and $ \ ((c,d), (e,f)) \in R \implies \  a + 2d = c+2b\ $ and $\  c + 2f = e + 2d \implies a + 2d + c + 2f = c+2b + e + 2d \implies a + 2f = 2b + e \implies a + 2f = e + 2b \implies ((a,b),(e,f)) \in R$

Hence the relation is transitive.

Therefore, the relation is an equivalence relation.

I am not quite sure if I have proved it correctly and if my approach is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your proof is perfectly correct. We can simplify the proof a little bit, especially the transitivity part, if we observe that $a+2d=c+2b$ is equivalent to $a-2b=c-2d$, as this way each side of the condition uses entries from the same pair.

Answer (score 6):

That's a correct direct approach. More generally note that $\,(a,b)\sim (c,d)\iff f(a,b) = f(c,d)\,$ for $\,f(u,v) = u-2v\,$ so we can  apply the following very general  **equivalence kernel** criterion.

---

It is straightforward to prove relations of  form $\rm\,  x\sim y {\overset{\ def}{\color{#c00}\iff}} f(x) = f(y)\, $ are equivalence relations.

More generally, suppose $\rm\ u\sim v\ \smash[t]{\overset{\ def}{\color{#c00}\iff}}\, f(u) \approx f(v)\ $ for a function $\rm\,f\,$ and equivalence relation $\,\approx.\, \ $ Then the equivalence relation $\rm\color{#0a0}{properties\ (E)}\,$  of $\,\approx\,$ transport (pullback) to $\,\sim\,$ along $\rm\,f$ as follows

- reflexive  $\rm\quad\ \color{#0a0}{\overset{(E)}\Rightarrow}\, f(v) \approx f(v)\:\color{#c00}\Rightarrow\:v\sim v$
- symmetric  $\rm\,\ u\sim v\:\color{#c00}\Rightarrow\ f(u) \approx f(v)\:\color{#0a0}{\overset{(E)}\Rightarrow}\:f(v)\approx f(u)\:\color{#c00}\Rightarrow\:v\sim u$
- transitive $\rm\ \ \ u\sim v,\, v\sim w\:\color{#c00}\Rightarrow\: f(u)\approx f(v),\,f(v)\approx f(w)\:\color{#0a0}{\overset{(E)}\Rightarrow}\:f(u)\approx f(w)\:\color{#c00}\Rightarrow u\sim w$

Such relations are called *(equivalence) kernels*. One calls $\, \sim\,$ the $\,(\approx)\,$ *kernel* of $\rm\,f.\,$ The equivalence classes $\,f_c = f^{-1}(c)\,$ are called the [fibers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89594/whats-the-name-for-the-equivalence-induced-by-a-function-on-its-domain) or [preimages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(mathematics)), or [level sets / curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set) of $f.$

Yours is the special case when $\,\approx\,$ is the equivalence relation of *equality*.

You can find many other examples of equivalence kernels in [prior answers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+equivalence+kernel)

See also the more general notions of [difference kernels and equalizers,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equalizer_(mathematics))

Answer (score 1):

If you rearrange the defining equation as $a-c=2b-2d$, or $\frac{b-d}{a-c}=\frac12$, you can find a geometric interpretation. We have $(a,b)\sim (c,d)$ if and only if $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ lie on the same line with a slope of $\frac12$. Geometrically, it is clear that this is an equivalence: any point is on the same line as itself; if point $P$ is on the same line as point $Q$, then point $Q$ is on the same line as $P$; if $P$ and $Q$ are on the same line, and so are $Q$ and $R$, then so are $P$ and $R$.

The equivalence classes under this relation are all lines with $\frac12$ slope.

Comment: This is a special case of the *equivalence kernel* viewpoint mentioned in my answer. Here the equivalence kernel of $\,f(x,y) = x-2y\,$ partitions the plane into  fiber (level set) equivalence classes having the form $\,f_c = f^{-1}(c) = $ all points $\,(x,y)\,$ on the line $\,x-2y = c.\ \ $

Comment: Yeah, it was reading your answer that inspired me to post this one. Thanks for the lesson on equivalence kernels! :) I just posted this separately for the geometric viewpoint, which might be accessible with or without understanding equivalence kernels in general.

Comment: Agreed, it is always instructive to emphasize familiar special cases of general results. I added some links on fibers to my answer.