# Proof that this relation about divisiblity is reflexive, transitive, ...

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, relations, symmetry

I can't handle this relation-evidence.

---

**$xRy \iff (\forall  t\in\mathbb{N}  \ \text{with $t$ a prime-number}: \ t\mid x \Rightarrow t\mid y)$**

($t\mid x$ means $t$ divides $x$; $t\mid y$ means $t$ divides $y$)

---

Now i have to prove

- *reflexivity: xRx*  `t|x => t|x`
- *transitivity:∃z∈N: xRy ∧ yRz => xRz* `(t|x => t|y)∧(t|y => t|z) => (t|x => t|z)`
- *symmetry: xRy <=> yRx* `(t|x => t|y) <=> (t|y => t|x)`
- *asymmetry: xRy => not(yRx)*  `(t|x => t|y) => not(t|y => t|x)`
- *antisymmetry: xRy ∧ yRx => x=y* `(t|x => t|y)∧(t|y => t|x) => (x=y)`

---

I have already shown that it's reflexive.

I also tried to show the other ones, but my proof was either wrong oder not concrete enough.

I also don't know, when $(t\mid x \Rightarrow t\mid y)$ from $t\mid x$ follows $t\mid y$, how can $(t\mid y \Rightarrow t\mid x)$ from $t\mid y$ follows $t\mid x$, and what the implication => means here. And because I don't understand it, i also can't show any example that proofs falseness.

So I am thankful for any help I can get.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $2\mid4$ but $4\nmid2$ — it’s not symmetric

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: BTW you could abbreviate "$\forall t\in\Bbb N$ with $t$ a prime-number" to "$\forall t\in\Bbb P$".

Comment: @J.W.Tanner your counterexample is incorrect.  Reread the problem statement again.  That being said, the relation *won't* be symmetric, but then again it won't be antisymmetric either.  Every prime divisor of $4$ divides $6$, but $6$ has a prime divisor that does not divide $4$.  As such $4\mathcal{R} 6$ but it is not true that $6\mathcal{R}4$.  On the other hand we have $4\mathcal{R} 8$ as well as $8\mathcal{R} 4$ as every prime divisor of each is the same despite $4\neq 8$.

Comment: Again, the relation rephrased is that $x$ is related to $y$ iff every prime divisor of $x$ is also a prime divisor of $y$.  It is possible for $y$ to have more prime divisors than $x$ has.

Comment: As an aside, I have changed the title of your question.  It was obvious that the relation in question is a relation.  Every subset of a cartesian product is a relation, nothing needed to be checked apart from its welldefinedness.  What you were actually asking was if it satisfied any of these properties.  Also, the relation "divisibility" as in $x$ is related to $y$ iff $x\mid y$ is a well known relation which people who read only your title might have thought you were talking about (*as evidenced by @J.W.Tanner's initial comment*) and is not the relation that your question was actually about.

Comment: @JMoravitz:  I see what you mean.  The original title asked for proof that divisibility is a relation, and I showed divisibility is not symmetric, but after more careful reading I see that the relation OP asked about is related to divisibility but not the usual divisible relation $x|y$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**  $\, x R y \!\iff\! \cal P_x \subseteq \cal P_y\,$ for $\,\cal P_n = $ set of prime factors of $\,n,\,$ reduces it to easy properties of $ $  '$\subseteq$'

**Remark** $ $ [Similarly](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2389834/242) many equivalence relations can be obtained via function pullback - see *equivalence kernels* (e.g. fibers, preimages, level sets / curves, etc).

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The $\Rightarrow$ means "implies" so $t\mid x\Rightarrow t\mid y$ means that whenever $x$ has $t$ as a factor so does $y$

For transitivity assume $xRy$ and $yRz$ and think as follows

$$
xRy\iff( t\mid x\Rightarrow \underline{t\mid y})
$$
also
$$
yRz\iff( \underline{t\mid y}\Rightarrow t\mid z).
$$
Now the underlined parts are the same so you have $t\mid x\Rightarrow t\mid z$ which is $xRz$ which we wanted to prove for transitivity.

You could try now the other ones

Hope this helped

Answer (score 1):

I assume the relation is given over $\mathbb{N}$

In order to show reflexivity, that is, $x\mathrel{R}x$ (for every $x\in\mathbb{N}$), you need to show that, given any prime number $t$, if $t\mid x$, then $t\mid x$. This is obviously true.

Is the relation antisymmetric? No: you can see that $2\mathrel{R}4$ and $4\mathrel{R}2$, but $2\ne 4$.

Transitivity. Suppose $x\mathrel{R}y$ and $y\mathrel{R}z$; you want to prove that $x\mathrel{R}z$. So, suppose $t$ is a prime with $t\mid x$; then $t\mid y$, because of $x\mathrel{R}y$, and therefore $t\mid z$, because of $y\mathrel{R}z$. The condition that $x\mathrel{R}z$ has been verified.

Try the others.