# $f,g\in P$ is a set of polynomials with coefficients in R. $fTg$ if $f-g=c$ for $\exists c\in R$. Show T is an equivalence relation on P

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, relations

$f,g\in P$ is a set of polynomials with coefficients in R. $fTg$ if $f-g=c$ for $\exists c\in R$. Show T is an equivalence relation on P

I'm assuming we can show it's symmetric because if f-g=c then g-f=-c, and since c is in R then -c is in R as well.

Then f-f=0 which is in R, but I don't know how to show it's transitive

Comment: Note $ f\,T\, g\iff  H(f) = H(g)\ $ where $H(p) = p-p(0),\,$ so it's a special case of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2389834/242) general result on *equivalence kernels* (whose proof is short and obvious).

Answer (score 1):

$f-g=c$ and $g-h=d$ implies $f-h =c+d$ by addition.